# javascript object key type vs Ruby hash key type. Javascript property notation

Tags: javascript, ruby, hash, properties

So in Ruby, we access keys by using symbols and strings when we actually want the value. When we type in hash["three"], Ruby probably takes the string and matches it in the hash that we defined. There is no conversion. See below:

```
[1] pry(main)> hash = {one:1, two:2, "three" => 3}
=> {:one=>1, :two=>2, "three"=>3}
[2] pry(main)> hash[:one]
=> 1
[3] pry(main)> hash["three"]
=> 3
```

In Javascript, what is going on behind the scenes?

```
 node
> js_object = {one:1, two:2, three:3}
{ one: 1, two: 2, three: 3 }
> js_object.one
1
> js_object[one]
ReferenceError: one is not defined
js_object["one"]
> 1
```

and then even more confusing:

```
js_object = {one:1, two:2, "three":3}
{ one: 1, two: 2, three: 3 }
```

Why in the last case does javascript take out the strings? Are they unnecessary or are the keys all implied strings? js_object.one should be looking for a key named "one" right but it seems like js_object does not contain keys as strings?

Here is what I read from Eloquent Javascript:

> "When using a dot, the part after the dot must be a valid variable
>   name, and it directly names the property. When using square brackets,
>   the expression between the brackets is evaluated to get the property
>   name. Whereas value.x fetches the property of value named “x”,
>   value[x] tries to evaluate the expression x and uses the result as the
>   property name."

Comment: `one` is a variable, `'one'` is a string. If `one='one'`, then `object[one]===1`

Comment: The phrase "*must be a valid variable name*" means that it must conform to the rules for variable names, not that it must be a variable.